# How to achieve transactional operations on in-memory data

Tags: c#, transactions

I've come across an issue where I need to implement a transaction of operations on in-memory objects with no backing memory store.

The example I'm working with is a vending machine where I need to both return change and vend an item when the customer makes a selection. There are failure cases for both operations, and I need information from the vended item (it's price) to complete the change request, but if either operation fails both need rolling back.

What I'm looking for is a general structure or pattern for making transactional code for in-memory C# objects, and any built-in technologies I can leverage (e.g. could I utilise TransactionScope?).